# indent is broken after saving back updated json dict to file

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary with many items in a json file:

```
{
"Create Code For Animals": {
    "mammals": {
        "dog": {
            "color": "brown", 
            "name": "John", 
            "legs": "four", 
            "tail": "yes"
        },
        "cat": {
            "color": "blue", 
            "name": "Johnny", 
            "legs": "four", 
            "tail": "yes"
        },
        "donkey": {
            "color": "grey", 
            "name": "Mickey", 
            "legs": "four", 
            "tail": "yes"
        }
```

I want to replace the name in each one of the animals, then save it back to the file, **AND** keep the indent as it was (as shown).
I'm using the following 2 methods for loading and dumping the original and updated dictionary.

All is working well (for changing the value and saving it back to the file) except the indent (format) of the lines is ruined after saving the file and the file is saved as one long line (with '\n' shown after the updated value).

I've tried using 'pickle' (as seen in one of the posts here), but this didn't work, made a mess of all the data in the file.

```
    def loadJson(self, jsonFilename):
        with open(FILE_PATH + '\\' + jsonFilename, 'r') as f:
           return json.load(f)

    def writeJson(self, jsonFilename, jsonDict):
        with open(FILE_PATH + '\\' + jsonFilename, 'w') as f:
           return json.dump(jsonDict, f)
```

Any help will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

json.dumps and dump have a parameter called indent

```
If ``indent`` is a non-negative integer, then JSON array elements and
    object members will be pretty-printed with that indent level. An indent
    level of 0 will only insert newlines. ``None`` is the most compact
    representation.  Since the default item separator is ``', '``,  the
    output might include trailing whitespace when ``indent`` is specified.
    You can use ``separators=(',', ': ')`` to avoid this
```

Something like this would do:

```
json.dump(jsonDict,f,indent=4)
```

Comment: Great! working! any idea how to get rid of the '\n' at the end of the updated value?

Comment: Sorry didn't understand the comment did you mean new lines at the end of the file?

Comment: exactly. new line.It's shown after the updated value. Other values stays the same (as they weren't updated)

Comment: well, if you indent you get new lines. That can't be avoided. If you are getting excessive number of new lines try the separator

Comment: Of course all this is cosmetic, the number of spaces in a json file has no relevence at all

Comment: Found it. Indeed not relevant but important. Using 'str.strip()' did the job. Anyway, thank you very much for the help.

Comment: glad to have helped